# Python3.6 can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Tags: python-3.x

When I run fab command, I got below error, I can't execute any fab task, even it is a simple print task. The error is on parse-task:

```
17:00:41  Traceback (most recent call last):
17:00:41    File "/bin/fab", line 8, in <module>
17:00:41      sys.exit(program.run())
17:00:41    File "/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 375, in run
17:00:41      self.parse_tasks()
17:00:41    File "/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 739, in parse_tasks
17:00:41      result = self.parser.parse_argv(self.core.unparsed)
17:00:41    File "/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/parser/parser.py", line 87, in parse_argv
17:00:41      ignore_unknown=self.ignore_unknown,
17:00:41    File "/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/invoke/parser/parser.py", line 208, in __init__
17:00:41      self.contexts = copy.deepcopy(contexts)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 306, in _reconstruct
17:00:41      value = deepcopy(value, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
17:00:41      state = deepcopy(state, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = copier(x, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
17:00:41      y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 306, in _reconstruct
17:00:41      value = deepcopy(value, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
17:00:41      state = deepcopy(state, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = copier(x, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
17:00:41      y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
17:00:41      state = deepcopy(state, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = copier(x, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
17:00:41      y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
17:00:41      state = deepcopy(state, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = copier(x, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
17:00:41      y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = copier(x, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
17:00:41      append(deepcopy(a, memo))
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
17:00:41      state = deepcopy(state, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
17:00:41      y = copier(x, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
17:00:41      y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
17:00:41    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
17:00:41      rv = reductor(4)
17:00:41  TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Snippets of my fabfile. I suspect if it is related to the initialization class.

Below inner class is to load data from files. like an initialization part. No multiple-threads.

```
class All_Slave_Data(object):  
    all_loaded_slave_data = {}

    def __init__(self, directory='.'):
        # Make this the default logger
        log = _globallog

        self.initialized = False
        # Load from multiple files.
        fileCount = 0

        # Do not descend into subdirectories
        filenames = [f for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(_basepath, 'slaves_*.yaml'))]
        for filename in filenames:
            <some file operations>
            self.all_loaded_slave_data.update(partial_data)


    def getData(self):
        if not self.all_loaded_slave_data:
            self.__init__()
        return self.all_loaded_slave_data


_allSlaveData = All_Slave_Data()
_the_slave_data = _allSlaveData.getData()
```

below is a simple task, I tried, actually I can't run any task.

```
@task  
def export_master_data(c, directory='.', log=_globallog):
   <some simple actions, from the error log, it did not touch the task body>
```

I could run the same fab command within python3.8.2 successfully.

If you have any clue or solution, that would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is approved to be an issue with Python3.6
The issue doesn't exist in Python3.7 and Python3.8.